# Passing two arrays to a function, using the data to initiate a button press. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, button

I have a list of items and a list of colors. I'm trying to make a clean function where you click a button representing the color ($colorCount) and it changes the color of the item ($itemList).

I'm trying to pass two arrays into a function to initiate the button press, When I log the code the arrays are showing up, but when I hit my target nothing is happening.

```
$itemList = ["RSST2","CM102"];
$colorCount = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
colorDisplay($itemList, $colorCount);

function colorDisplay($c, $b) {
    console.log ($c);
    console.log ($b);
   $("#target-"+$c+"-"+$b).click(function(){

        console.log ("button clicked " + $b);
        $("#"+$c+"-"+$b).addClass("active-img");
        $("#"+$c+"-"+$b).removeClass("waiting-img");
        $("#"+$c+"-"+$b).siblings().addClass("waiting-img");

    });
}
```

My HTML is this... I'm using wordpress and an ACF repeater field

```
<div class="prod-img-cont">
<?$z=0;
    if( have_rows('additional_colors' , $product_item->ID) ):

    while ( have_rows('additional_colors', $product_item->ID) ) : the_row();
    $color_images = get_sub_field('color_images', $product_item->ID);
?>
<img class="<?php if( ($z) == "0" ){
    echo "active-img";
    } else {
        echo "waiting-img";
    }?>" id="<?=$product_name;?>-<?=$z;?>" src="<?=$color_images;?>">
<?
 $z++;
endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;?>
</div>
<div class="product-list-item-right">
    <div class="additional-colors">
        <h2>Available Colors:</h2>
        <div class="color-grid">
            <?$z=0;
            if( have_rows('additional_colors' , $product_item->ID) ):
            while ( have_rows('additional_colors', $product_item->ID) ) : the_row();
            $color_choice = get_sub_field('color_sample', $product_item->ID);
            ?>
            <button class="color-choice" id="target-<?=$product_name;?>-<?=$z;?>" style="background-color:<?=$color_choice;?>"></button>
            <?
             $z++;
            endwhile;

            else :

                // no rows found

            endif;?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the $itemList array is referring to the $product_name in the PHP and I'm looping through the rows to get the $colorCount number

I feel like my thought process is correct, but I'm missing something basic that isn't giving me output i need.

Comment: You can't use an entire array like this `$("#target-"+$c+"-"+$b)`

Comment: Unless your element has the id "target-RSST2,CM102-0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20" :).

Comment: I kind of though thats what was happening...

Comment: If you can elaborate on what is it you're trying to do, including a [mcve], in this case the HTML and CSS as well, we can probably resolve the issue

Comment: @StevenCipparulo, welcome to the community, but I don't know why you are assigning an event like this '$("#target-"+$c+"-"+$b)', while $c and $b are arrays, this is not correct

Comment: @Sarvesh, you're correct that is wrong, I though it would be.

Comment: @j08691 I edited the post to show my HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you define the selectors - as other people already mentioned, when you try to concatenate a string with an array, JavaScript will convert the array to a comma-separated list of entries, something like this:

"abc-" + [1,2,3] ==> "abc-1,2,3"

Which is not what you are trying to do. In this case, you could try to benefit from the event bubbling (click events "bubble" up the DOM) and attach the listener to the top container (#product-list-item-right). In that listener you would inspect the original event target and if it was something staring with "#target-", then you would parse out the color code and product ID and then select/manipulate the appropriate elements

Hope that helps!